# Prolog recursivly build list based on dot product

Tags: prolog

Hi I have a prolog function/predicate? that takes the dot product of two list. and would like to use it to write a function that builds a list of dot products from a list and a list of list. So basically, the dot product will be called on each list in the list of list the function dot is below and it works.

```
dot([], [], 0).
dot([Head|Tail], [Head2|Tail2], Result) :-
    Prod = Head * Head2,
    dot(Tail, Tail2, Remaining),
    Result is Prod + Remaining.
```

This is my attempt at the function that fails every-time I try to run it. Can any one help?

```
dotAll([], [[]], [0]).
dotAll(X, [[Head]|[Tail]], Result) :-
    dotUnit(X, Head, Prod),
    Result = [Prod|Result],
    dotAll(X, Tail, Result).
```

To sum of my goal, if I passed in this `dotAll([1,2,3],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]], What).` I would like to get back, `What` is `[15,32,15]`.

I know that is a mouth full but i hope some one can give me some pointers on where im going wrong. Im very new to prolog.

Comment: Note that `[Head]` is a list with one element, `Head`. And `[Tail]` is a list with one element, `Tail`. So `[[Head]|[Tail]]` is a list of two elements which are lists, `[Head]` and `[Tail]`. You probably didn't mean that. Querying `dotAll([1,2,3],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]], What).` then fails because `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3]]` is not a list of just two elements. In Prolog, just treat it as a list: `[Head|Tail]`. Your `dotUnit` will do the right thing with the list. Likewise, `[[]]` is not the empty list. It's a list with one element, `[]`.

Comment: Ok so I treat list of list like list. Still though, if I strip out the extra brackets, I still get a fail. I don't really see what is wrong with the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dotAll` predicate I believe (from the example) is defined to be:

```
dotAll(Vector, ListOfVectors, Results)
```

And says that `Results` is the list of dot product results obtained by taking the dot product of `Vector` with each vector in `ListOfVectors`.

Reviewing the `dotAll` predicate:

```
dotAll(X, [Head|Tail], [Prod|Result]) :-  % dotAll of X with [Head|Tail]
                                          %   is [Prod|Result] if...
    dot(X, Head, Prod),                   % Prod is the dot product of X w/Head
    %Result = [Prod|Result],              % This would always fail
    dotAll(X, Tail, Result).              % AND Result is the list of
                                          %   dot products of X with Tail
```

Notes about the recursive case:

1. The `Result = [Prod|Result]` would fail since this is saying, *I have `Result` and it's the same thing as `[Prod|Result]`* which cannot be true.
2. You can use the third argument in the clause, as shown, to express what the result list will look like in the recursive case (`[Prod|Result]`)

Then the base case:

```
dotAll(_, [], []).                       % dot product of anything with
                                         % an empty list of vectors is empty
```

Notes about the base case:

1. The first argument is not `[]` because your recursive predicate doesn't reduce the first argument down to an empty list. The first argument is always the vector you started with which is used to dot product with the elements in the vector list (second argument). Since we don't care what the vector is in the base case, we use `_`.
2. The second argument is `[]`, the empty list since the base case is about what happens when we've exhausted the list of vectors, which is a list of lists. When you get to the end of a lists of lists, you have an empty list (`[]`).
3. The third argument is the empty list `[]` not `[0]` because it's logical: if you take the dot product of any vector with an empty vector list, you should get no results (an empty list `[]`).

Using the above corrections:

```
| ?- dotAll([1,2,3],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], R).

R = [14,32,50] ? ;

no
```